# How do I loop a intergerFIeld in django templates?

Tags: python, django

I have to loop an element according to the dynamic data. I have an INTeger Field.
Here's what I want to loop:

> `<li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></li>`

about 5 times max and 1 min.

My model:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='clients/', null=True)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
company = models.ForeignKey(connectedCompanies, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
rating_Given = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Rating out of 5: ', null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
post = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

@property
def get_rating_Given_range(self):
    return range(self.rating_Given)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the model property that converts IntegerField to range object:

in model:

```
@property
def get_rating_Given_range(self):
    return range(self.rating_Given or 0) #change 0 to 1 if you need to loop at least 1.
```

in template

```
{% for i in objetc.get_intfield_range %}
    <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not working if using the model.field.get_intfield_range in the template then it shows nothing and if using model.get_intfield_range it shows a error 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Share your model with the IntegrerField

Comment: added in question

Comment: You can see updated answer!